# Having content or image fadeIN with jquery when using inner html

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you go about fading content or an image when using javascripts innerHTML.

I tried many things but my lack of knowledge in javascript/jquery is making it difficult.

```
function swapLogo(){
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById("logo").innerHTML='<img src="images/logo_filled.gif"/>'.fadeIn('slow');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it, change the HTML and then fade it in.

```
$("#logo").hide().html('<img src="images/logo_filled.gif"/>').fadeIn('slow');
```